# SSRS Matrix Grand Total

Tags: reporting-services, grouping

I have the followin matrix that shows a total per year, and I need to show the grand total across all years below that. Here is my current Matrix with the yearly totals:

[image]

I have the grand total stored in a variable but I'm struggling to get the formatting correct.

The closest that I have got is to add the grand total as the first row. To do this I right click on the year column > Add Group > Group by x > Select Add Group Header > OK. Then delete the extra column that was added.

It doesn't matter if I select add header or add footer, it always places the new row above the existing row. How do I put this total row at the bottom of the matrix? I need to have the total value span across all year columns and centered.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What happens when, instead of `Add Group`, you try `Add Total` -> `After` in the **Grouping** tab, clicking the appropriate row group's dropdown arrow as required?

Comment: That just adds another row that is the same as the per year row. If I add total after to the column group then it adds another column with the summed totals. Unfortunately neither of those produce the formatting that I need.

Comment: I would go back to the report designer and argue that the requested format is confusing and does not follow common reporting practise - normally this would be an additional column at the far right, which can also present monthly totals across all years.

Comment: I'll try my luck with that if I can't find a solution. Their proposed layout makes sense in this case however, as the monthly totals are meaningless and they'd like to use up as little width as possible for printing.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a group adjacent below. You would need to group by a variable that is unique in the context of the matrix, so that the resulting adjacent row group has only one row. Then manually write the expression for the aggregate you want in the relevant cell.